# Storing Params in a Session with Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, controller

I am using Rails 4.

I have subarticles nested into articles. I am storing all of the form data from subarticles in a session when a user needs to create an account before submission.

Here is what I am using (subarticles_controller):

```
def create
  if current_user.nil?

  session[:subarticle] = params

  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

Then after the user signs up, it creates the subarticle with the stored params using

```
if session[:subarticle].present?
  @subarticle = current_user.subarticles.create(session[:subarticle]["subarticle"])

  session[:subarticle] = nil

  flash[:notice] = "Awesome, you are logged in and your answer is undergoing review."      

  edit_user_registration_path
end
```

I am having trouble, however, saving the article_id in which the subarticle is created under. Can someone point me in the right direction to doing this?

Comment: Is the (parent) article actually persisted to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach could be to save the (sub)articles created by guest users in the database.

```
class SubArticlesController < ApplicationController 

  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ...

  def create
    @subarticle = Article.new(article_params) do |a|
      if current_user
        a.user = current_user
      else
        a.token = SecureRandom.hex
      end
    end
    if @subarticle.save
      if @subarticle.user
        redirect_to @subarticle
      else
        session[:after_sign_in_path] = edit_article_path(@subarticle, token: @subarticle.token)
        redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'Please sign in to finalize your article.'
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    if @subarticle.user.nil? && @subarticle.token != params[:token]
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'You are not authorized.'
    end

    flash[:notice] = 'Please press save again to publish your post.' unless @subarticle.user
    render :edit
  end

  def update 
    # The @subarticle.token should be included in the edit form 
    unless @subarticle.user && @subarticle.token == params[:sub_article][:token]
      # let the current user claim the article
      @subarticle.user = current_user
    end

    if @subarticle.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @subarticle
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def set_article
    @subarticle = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def sub_article_params
    params.require(:sub_article).permit(...)
  end
end
```

So here we we instead give the user a link to the edit page for the article where he/she can "finish" the article after logging in.

Since a malicious user could potentially "steal" unclaimed articles by guessing the id and entering the edit url we add a random token which we store in the database with the article and add to the url. Not 100% foolproof but at least better.

To make this work you will also need to add a token field to your form:

```
<%= form_for(@subarticle) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field :token %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The reason you might want to consider this is because session storage is often memory based and if you have a large amount of traffic storing the entire params hash in the session will exhaust the server memory. Also you should reset the session before logging a user in or out to avoid session fixation.

We do have a few issues though - first we don't want to accumulate a bunch of "unclaimed" articles if the user (or a bot) never logs in. The easiest way to do this is to setup a cron job to delete articles over a certain age without an associated user.

You would also want to filter any articles without a user from you show/index action.

Comment: Of course putting the token in the url still makes it vulnerable to man in the middle attacks if you are not using HTTPS. However it might be "good enough" security.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth answer and recommending a better solution. I am most likely going to go this route, but if I wanted to continue with my way, how would I be able to get the article ID to save in there? My goal is to later call `subarticle.article.title` but I receive an error since it can't find the article. Also, I don't have to worry about someone stealing an article as users cannot edit articles after submission (cancancan). Should have been more clear. Thank you again. @max

Comment: You have to save it to the database first to get an id - ID's in ActiveRecord are just auto incrementing database columns.